# Java mysql resultSet error

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

Ok so basically I have this code:

```
    preparedStatement = connect
      .prepareStatement("select * from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS where NAZWISKO= ? ; ");
      preparedStatement.setString(1, surname3);

while (resultSet.next()) {

    String id = resultSet.getString("i

d");
          String user = resultSet.getString("IMIE");
          String website = resultSet.getString("NAZWISKO");
          String summary = resultSet.getString("ADRES");
          String date = resultSet.getString("EMAIL");
          String comment = resultSet.getString("TELEFON");
          String opisso = resultSet.getString("OPIS");


          JTextField myOutput = new JTextField(1600);
    myOutput.setText("id w bazie danych to " + id + " imie to " + user + " nazwisko to " + website + " adres to " + summary + " email to " + date + " teelefon to " + comment + " opis to " + opisso);



         add(myOutput);
    }
```

error:
the query went fine but , the error appears here   "while (resultSet.next())"

```
 SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jdbcexample.Main.readDataBase(Main.java:416)
    at jdbcexample.Main$7.mousePressed(Main.java:346)
```

How I should fix it?

Comment: Well, man, your `resultSet` is `null`.

Comment: Did you do a `preparedStatement.executeQuery()` or like before iterating over the `ResultSet` ?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to do :

```
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

That's why your result set is `null`, because you did not initialize it with the value returned by executing your prepared statement. Your resultSet being null, results in accesing a null reference ( `null.next()`) which results in a [NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

to get the resultset you have to execute the query

`ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();`